# Append multiple types of letter to elements in a list

Tags: r

I have a list of string elements:

```
example <- c("test1", "test2", "test3")
```

How do I append `_A` and `_B` separately to each element in the list? This is the desired output:

```
example_solution <- c("test1_A", "test1_B", "test2_A", "test2_B", "test3_A", "test3_B")
```

Thank you!

Comment: I removed the [tag:dplyr] tag since you're just dealing with vectors. If you really need a `dplyr`-solution, please edit your question to alter your sample data (to be a frame) and/or provide more context as to why vector-ops like my answer won't quite work for you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base R:

```r
c(outer(example, c("_A", "_B"), FUN = paste0))
# [1] "test1_A" "test2_A" "test3_A" "test1_B" "test2_B" "test3_B"
```

If order is important, `t`ranpose the inner matrix:

```r
c(t(outer(example, c("_A", "_B"), FUN = paste0)))
# [1] "test1_A" "test1_B" "test2_A" "test2_B" "test3_A" "test3_B"
```